Winterbash 2016
Winter Bash is a fun, lighthearted event SE runs every year as a way of celebrating the many amazing people who make the communities awesome. It's open to any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate.
During Winter Bash, users earn virtual hats by completing certain tasks. They're sort of like badges, but they're more visible and less permanent. Hats can be "worn" on users' avatars just about anywhere avatars show up on the network. Here's an example of what some hats looked like last year, taken from the network leaderboard:

Of course, SE is rolling out an all-new assortment of hats for this year's event, as they have in the past.
The Details
This year's event will start soon. Users will be able to see all the hats they've earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have an FAQ to explain how things work.
Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.
The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer. Last year there was also a snowflake icon in the top black bar, which opened a control panel. Is this no longer the case?

@FedericoPoloni Winterbash hasn't yet started.

I know, but my question still stands. Will those two be the only visual changes to the site?

@FedericoPoloni: We really don't know nothing about that.

@Charo Then why claiming that the only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer, if you don't know for sure?

@FedericoPoloni That sentence is taken directly from the mail I got from the staff announcing the Winterbash and asking for discussing it among the site members.

@egreg So it's confirmed that what the staff wrote to you was not the truth. They should be on Santa's list of naughty kids for this year.

@FedericoPoloni In the footer of the pop up window when you click on the snowflake you find the “I hate hats” button. I see no difference from last year.

Yes, but it's different from what they promised: The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer. Nothing about snowflakes in the header bar.

@FedericoPoloni: You're right!!

I don't think that the message itself is much different from last year's.

@egreg: Yes, it's more or less the same.

Upvote = Yes! Please sign us up for hats!
Downvote = No thank you, I'd rather enjoy a regular day at the office.

I find all this very funny, so I'm happy that our site is participating in Winter Bash again.
Now you can see our hats here.

Vedo che è arrivata la Befana! Nel mio quartiere, Gaspare, Melchiorre e Baldassarre sono arrivati da alcuni giorni e ogni sera si organizzano lunghe code di bambini che vogliono consegnargli le loro lettere.
